# Sum of a column value of table B in table A, is there a automated way ? Is it good practice ? - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically each user has a team, and each team has 11 players, so whenever a player scores they earn some points. Now is there a automated way to do this -
As in when there is a update/entry in the `USER_TEAM_PLAYERS` table, summate the points of all players to the `USER_TEAM` table for the corresponding user in some column (in this case `TEAM_TOTAL` column).

I have two tables:

1. `USER_TEAM` with columns `USER_ID`, `TEAM_TOTAL`
2. `USER_TEAM_PLAYERS` with columns `PLAYER_NAME`, `PLAYER_POINTS`, `USER_ID`

Example:

TABLE - `USER_TEAM`

```
USER_ID | TEAM_TOTAL
---------------------
    1   |   40
    2   |   50
```

TABLE - `USER_TEAM_PLAYERS`

```
PLAYER_NAME | PLAYER_POINTS | USER_ID
-------------------------------------
Adam        |    10         |   1
Alex        |    30         |   1
Botas       |    40         |   2
Pepe        |     5         |   2
Diogo       |     5         |   2
```

Comment: (1) You can use triggers to do this "automatically".  (2) Why not just store the values at the team level and then calculate on the fly?

Comment: That's what triggers were designed for.

Comment: I think we can do this by a trigger on `USER_TEAM_PLAYERS` for any update/insert and run a procedure for that trigger to calculate the total. 

but is it efficient for a app that might have large user base ? for every update after each sec i might end up running the same procedure multiple times. Is it best practice ?

Comment: A trigger that updates a single row should be pretty fast (assuming you have the right indexes). It doesn't need to re-compute the whole team score, but can work incrementally instead.

Comment: basically if we consider 18 teams playing at once, each having 11 players, so ~200 players, all updating their individual points each sec, and thousands of users having players within those 200. So in that case will it be apt ? @TheImpaler

Comment: Calculate the team total on the fly when you need it, but don't store it. This is the easiest way to ensure consistency. If you don't have millions of records, you should not have performance problems with this approach.

Comment: i think on the fly is a better approach as i don't have to worry about the number of live users @OlivierJacot-Descombes,

Comment: Okay, then you can use @Dri372's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first table should be only a view of the second one

```
CREATE VIEW USER_TEAM2 AS 
   SELECT USER_ID, SUM(PLAYER_POINTS) AS TEAM_TOTAL 
   FROM USER_TEAM_PLAYERS
   GROUP BY USER_ID
   ORDER BY USER_ID;
```

Doing this, you have no duplicate data and a view can be in SELECT, ... like a table.

Nota 1 : I used the name USER_TEAM2 because your first table still exists but you can delete it.

Nota 2 : If you want to have some specific data to the TEAM_TABLE, keep the 2 names, and modifify your view as needed by adding some fields with a JOIN of this first table.

Comment: Okay but the team table is still useful to know the available teams and you could add it a team name, for instance.

Comment: Ok so keep your TEAM_TABLE and your view with a different name and add in the select what you want by a JOIN on the TEAM_TABLE. I update my answer with this.